# How is Apple's fabric texture generated?

Tags: textures

Apple uses this texture in a lot of its products now:

[image]

And here's a closer look:

[image]

You can see that it's not just a bunch of lines: there's an element of randomness to it. Generally speaking, how can this be accomplished? I'm not interested so much in the implementation as I am in the concept. I've looked online, but couldn't find any hints. If the concept is too broad to be fully covered here, I'd be very happy with some reading material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The techniques that you should look into are called [texture synthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_synthesis) and [procedural texture generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_texture). In the literature there are many algorithms that can generate a randomly but realistically looking texture based on a sample texture (e.g., a photo of a rock, marble or other material) or based on input parameters (amount of randomness, structure of the texture, et cetera). Some algorithms are pretty amazing in what they can accomplish.